# How to set different name for layers that are created inside for loop in framerJS

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

I like to set different layer name for layers that are created inside the for loop. Following is the code that is working, but it creates three layers named "circle" which prevents me from doing anything specific to let's say the second circle

```
for i in [1..3]
    circle =  new Layer
        x: 15 + i*50
        y: 15
        height:10
        width:10
```

I tried doing circle[i] but it didn't work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create array of layers:

```
circles = []
for i in [1..3]
    circles.push new Layer
        x: 15 + i*50
        y: 15
        height: 10
        width: 10
```

or more coffeescript'ish (thx @moo_is_too_short)

```
circles = for i in [1..3]
    new Layer
        x: 15 + i*50
        y: 15
        height: 10
        width: 10
```

And access:

```
circles[0]
circles[1]
circles[2]
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you, Tomasz. It never came to my mind to create an array. It works perfectly.

Comment: You could say `circles = for i in [1..3]...` rather than `circles.push` inside the loop.